# Load Data Infile - negative decimal truncated (to positive number)

Tags: sql, mysql, decimal

I am having trouble loading decimal data into a database - specifically, my negative numbers are getting truncated, and I can't figure it out.

Here is what my query looks like:

```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    mydecimal DECIMAL(13,2),PRIMARY KEY(id));
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.dat' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';
```

And the data.dat that I'm loading:

```
;000000019.50 ;
;000000029.50-;
;000000049.50 ;
```

When it completes, giving me a warning that "Data truncated for column 'mydecimal' at row 2."  And when I look at the data, it's stored as positive number.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle data abnormalities like this in the input file is to load them into a local variable, then set the actual column value based on a transformation of the local variable.

In your case, you can load the strings into a local variable, then either leave it alone or multiply by negative one depending on whether it ends with a minus sign.

Something like this should work for you:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.dat' 
INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
(id,@mydecimal)
set mydecimal = IF(@mydecimal like '%-',@mydecimal * -1,@mydecimal);
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked perfectly, and on my 1GB test file took 33 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're putting the minus sign after the number rather than before it.  Does it work when you place the '-' sign at the start of the line?

Comment: I tried that, but it still didn't work.  Wish I could magically transform the location of the '-' signs.  I could use sed to strip the '-' and put it in another column, but that seems a bit backwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INT(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
mydecimal varchar(255),PRIMARY KEY(id));

LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.dat' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';

update mytable set mydecimal = 
cast(mydecimal as decimal(13,2))*if (substring(mydecimal, -1)='-', -1, 1);

alter table mytable modify column mydecimal decimal(13,2) signed;
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked well.  I didn't know about casts or substrings either!  As a benchmark, Ike's method worked quicker on a 1GB data set coming in at 33.1 seconds... whereas this took 27.33+32.77+23.15 = 83.25 seconds.